# Sumarising a table

Tags: sql-server, summary

Using SQL Server I'm trying to summarize a questionnaire table as follows but am struggling!

I want to show the % of all Questionnaires answered true by month and year.

[image]

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with conditional aggregation.  This method shows conditional use of `avg()`:

```
select "Year", "Month",
       avg(case when recommend = 'true' then 1.0 else 0.0 end) * 100 as "True %"
from Questionnaire q
group by "Year", "Month"
order by "Year", "Month";
```

If you actually want the "%" at the end, you need to convert the result to a string and append it.